# SalesforceDX Stopped working

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Went to try and use SFDX tonight (it was working a few days ago) and received the following

Plugin "salesforcedx" v41 or later may only be installed in a v6.0.0 or later CLI. 41.3.0

I tried to run `sfdx update` and received

> sfdx-cli: Updating salesforcedx@latest to 41.3.0...Plugin "salesforcedx" v41 or later may only be installed in a v6.0.0 or later CLI. 41.3.0
>
> !
>
> ▸    Error installing plugin salesforcedx

I uninstalled the salesforcedx plugin and tried to reinstall it and received same error...

Any ideas on how to recover or am I dead in the water?

Comment: Just tweeted and wade the product owner said they are looking into this issue !!!

Comment: I am wondering if there is another url where every version is maintained.

Comment: Can you tell us the version of your CLI? Type: sfdx version

Comment: Here is mine sfdx-cli/5.7.7-94c4196 (darwin-amd64) go1.7.5 sfdxstable

Comment: @Wade - I believe it was 40.x.x. It was last updated (vis sfdx update) this week.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - Are you having the same issue? - FYI, I uninstalled the `salesforcedx` plugin. redownloaded the pkg file (mac) and installed it overtop, then it updated and appears to now be working.....bit of a pain

Comment: Eric, I need the CLI version, not the plugin.

Comment: I run via CI and looks fine .I did the following after uninstalling everything wget -qO- https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz | tar xJf -
./sfdx/install
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx

Comment: @Wade - Sorry, I uninstalled it already

Comment: I’ll write this up shortly as an answer, but I believe you were running the CLI for the pilot (very old). It would have been version 5.6, and is not updatable to version 6. We told everyone at the beginning and end of pilot they’d have to uninstall the pilot bits. Sorry for the challenge.

Comment: Welcome @wade to Salesforce,Stackexchange.com .Appreciate your time here! We have all the questions related to DX with tag https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforcedx

Comment: @Wade - It is possible. I installed the CLI during the beta then got busy I performed an SFDX update this week and it said it updated. It must have updated to the latest beta version....Does that fit your thinking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you downloaded the Salesforce CLI during the Salesforce DX Pilot, you likely have version 5.6.X. Unfortunately, this is not upgradable to version 6 of the CLI. You'll have to uninstall. When you go to uninstall, be aware that it was using `heroku` in the binary path name, so you'll need to use this script from Dave Carroll: [uninstall Salesforce CLI from Pilot](https://gist.github.com/dcarroll/7d7a4b97a0d77f26c9f6fc6d73b689a6).

If you have version 5.7.X or higher, you should be able to upgrade by running `sfdx update`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get permission denied when trying to run that script on the heroku stuff. The heroku version is `heroku-cli/5.6.22-f9533ba (darwin-amd64) go1.7.3 sfdx`. I downloaded and installed the current Heroic CLI over top, will that suffice?

Comment: Yes, these commands need to be run with `sudo`.

Comment: Also, the salesforcedx plugin is now "core" plugin, meaning it does not need to be installed separately..

Comment: Fyi, we were able to uninstall the sfdx pilot binaries and install the latest version without removing the heroku binary or using `sudo` so that may not be necessary for everyone ...

Answer (score 4):

Equivalent instructions for Windows:

1. Uninstall **SFDX CLI**
   [image]
2. For good measure, uninstall the Heroku CLI as well
   [image]
3. delete %HOMEPATH%\.config\sfdx directory if it exists
4. Reinstall from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli
5. Trigger the CLI to check for updates - `sfdc update`
   [image]

Comment: If sfdx hangs on windows 7, you can delete the entire sfdx directory under <home directory>\appData\Local\sfdx.  Then run sfdx update and it will re-download the latest version.